# Send to paypal using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, curl, paypal, oauth, paypal-sandbox

Hi i'm beginner in angularjs and i want to convert this request curl in angularjs ?

```
curl https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
  --insecure \
  -d METHOD=name \
  -d VERSION=XX.0 \
  -d USER=API-Username \
  -d PWD=API-Password \
  -d SIGNATURE=API-Signature \
  -d ...
```

I use a $http like this :

```
$http({

                     url: 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp',
                     method: 'POST',
                     headers: {

                         'Content-Type': 'application/json',

                     }, 
                            data: {
                                'USER=bjaoui.rimaggggggg-.......gmail.com',
                                      'PWD=tgttgtg....',
                                      'SIGNATURE=AFcWxVyyyyyyy',
                                      'METHOD=SetExpressCheckout',
                                      'VERSION=112.0',
                                      'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE',
                                      'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19',
                                      'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD',
                                      'cancelUrl=http://www.example.com/cancel.html',
                                      'returnUrl=http://www.example.com/success.html',
                                  } 


                    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                 console.log(data);



                     }).error(function (error) {
                                 //console.log(data);
                                  alert("error:"+JSON.stringify(error));
                     });
```

but i found always error in syntaxe of data .what's the problem any help please

Comment: Realize that doing so with [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) will **expose** your Paypal `username`, `password`, `api-signature`, and so on, to the world.

Comment: look please i edit my question @EdSF

Comment: Please read and understand previous comment. **Do not share your credential information with anyone. Store in a secure location with limited access**. [Creating and managing NVP/SOAP API credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the &'s in the NVP request. The final result should end up being like

```
USER=something&PWD=something&SIGNATURE=...
```

It looks like yours is going to end up without the &'s, so the API system can't tell that you're sending the METHOD at all.